# From areas of several species ranges (polygons) to a map (raster) expressing the count of overlapping polygons

Tags: raster, r, polygon, distribution, species

I am not able to resolve the problem that follows. I have some separate shapefiles files, each one representing a given species range. Some layers have multiple polygons.

I would prefer to solve this problem with R syntax, but as alternative option I could use QGIS.

After import these shapefiles and merging them, I would like to obtain a map representing the count of overlapping polygons. In other terms, my final output would be a sort of “heatmap” in which each cell has the value of the count of overlapping polygons (i.e. the sum of the species falling in a given cell).

Anyone could kind provide me the operative approach to accomplish this?

If required, I can provide the example layers that I'm using during my trials. Despite many many attempts, I have not reached any result.

Comment: `rasterize` each polygon object into a binary (0/1) presence/absence raster, and then make that into a stack and then sum the stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either do what Spacedman suggests (rasterize and sum) or work directly on the polygons:

```
library(raster)
sp1 <- spPolygons(rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20)), attr=data.frame(sp=1))
sp2 <- spPolygons(rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0)), attr=data.frame(sp=2))
sp3 <- spPolygons(rbind(c(-125,-20), c(-125,20), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,-20)), attr=data.frame(sp=3))

x <- list(sp1, sp2, sp3)
```

This gives an rgeos error (TopologyException) on the example data, but might work on your data:

```
#y <- do.call(bind, x)
#u <- union(y)
```

Alternatively:

```
u <- x[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    u <- union(u, x[[i]])
}
```

Now sum the numer of species:

```
u$nspp <- rowSums(data.frame(u), na.rm=TRUE)
```

And plot

```
spplot(u, 'nspp')
```

If you want a raster

```
r <- raster()
r <- rasterize(u, r, 'nspp')
plot(r)
```